# Sorting elements with user defined dynamic containers

Tags: c++, sorting, methods, user-defined

I have some problems sorting elements on C++. Unluckily, I cannot use C++ containers (professor's request) so I created a new container called 'vettore' whose structure is conceptually similar to a list.
So I was trying to sort the ints contained in a 'vettore' structure, but with the following code, giving as input 100, 10, 1 I receive 1, 100, 100. I'm really not getting why it is not working.
This is the method of class "vettore" which should sort the elements:

```
void ordina(){
    vettore<T>*aux=this;
    vettore<T>*punt_a_min=aux;
    bool sentinella=0;
    T min=aux->get_my();

    while(aux->get_next()!=nullptr){
        aux=aux->get_next();

        if(aux->get_my()<min){
            sentinella=1;  
            min=aux->get_my();
            punt_a_min=aux;
        }
    }

    if(sentinella==1){ 
        punt_a_min->set_obj(this->get_my());              
        this->set_obj(min);
    }

    if(this->get_next()!=nullptr) 
        *(this->get_next()).ordina();                  
};
```

And this is the "vettore" class (for what is needed):

```
template<class T> class vettore{
      private:
              T my_object; //container
              vettore <T> * next; //puntatore al prossimo elemento della lista
      public:
              vettore():next(nullptr){}; //default constructor
              vettore(T oggetto, vettore <T> * successivo=nullptr):next(successivo),my_object(oggetto){}; //faccio puntare la lista a quell'elemento 

              vettore(const vettore <T> &x):next(x.next),my_object(x.my_object){}; //copy constructor

              ~vettore(){//destructor
                  if(next!=nullptr){
                      delete next;
                      next=nullptr;
                  }
              };

              vettore <T> * get_next(){
                  return next;
              };

              T get_my(){
                  return my_object;
              };

              T& get_obj(){ //ottenere l'oggetto by reference
                  return my_object;
              };       

              void ordina(){
                  //vettore<T>*new_this=this;
                  vettore<T>*aux=this;
                  vettore<T>*punt_a_min=aux;
                  bool sentinella=0;
                  T min=aux->get_my();

                  while(aux->get_next()!=nullptr){
                      aux=aux->get_next();

                      if(aux->get_my()<min){
                          sentinella=1;  
                          min=aux->get_my();
                          punt_a_min=aux;
                      }
                  }

                  if(sentinella==1){ 
                      punt_a_min->set_obj(this->get_my());              
                      this->set_obj(min);
                  }

                  if(this->get_next()!=nullptr)
                      *(this->get_next()).ordina();                  
              };

              void set_next(vettore<T>*e){
                  next=e;
              }

              void set_obj(T obj){
                  my_object=obj;
              };
          };
```

And if this is not correct (or just for curiosity), is there a sort function for a dynamic arrays declared as `int * a = new int [n]`?
 Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a comment: you might consider using one language only for names and comments. English that is. :)

Comment: I'm afraid you implemented a list, not a vector (which is conceptually different, very different)

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work to do `std::sort(a, a + n);` - of course, whether that is allowed when you are not allowed to use standard containers is of course a different matter.